# Date comparison in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

in c# 4.0, How to check date in text box, the date is greater than or equal

```
DateTime StartDate =  Convert.ToDateTime(TxtStrtDate.Text);
DateTime ExpirationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtExpDte.Text);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask and mark the answers to your questions.

Comment: How can I improve this question due to negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Compare()` is the easiest way I can think of.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
bool b = ExpirationDate >= StartDate;
```

Read this [DateTime.GreaterThanOrEqual Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_greaterthanorequal)

OR

```
int i = DateTime.Compare(ExpirationDate, StartDate);

//if ExpirationDate is less than StartDate then result is Less than zero

//if ExpirationDate equals StartDate then result is Zero

//if ExpirationDate is greater than StartDate then result is Greater than zero
```

Comment: @user1196392: Which one `>=` or `Compare`

Comment: how i m aget the less or more than zero.plz write the if condition

Comment: @user1196392: Here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12336/chat-room-for-nikhil-agrawal-and-user1196392

Comment: @user1196392: don't post your email address in a public forum...what if this is the email you log into stack overflow with... I'd delete that comment to be safe :)